# How to get all SQL extended event sessions on server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to query on the server for all extended event sessions, with **state** : **started** and **stopped**.

This query is returning only the sessions with **state** = **started** :

```
select [Name], create_time from sys.dm_xe_sessions
```

Can you please provide a way (if possible) which returns all the extended event sessions on the server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look in [sys.server_event_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-event-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table:

```
select * from sys.server_event_sessions
```

[sys.dm_xe_sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-xe-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns information about an active extended events session only.

Comment: I need the date of creation too but this doesn't give me that information unfortunately, and I can't make an inner join with sys.dm_xe_sessions either as that doesn't give me the stopped sessions, can you please give me a solution for the creation date too ? Thank you !!

Comment: Unfortunately, `create_time` do not return the time, when the session has been created, but the time when it has been started. You can easily confirm that by starting/stopping existing sessions and querying `sys.dm_xe_sessions` DMV. I do not know a way to tell when an event session has been created, unless you look at some audit log, event session capture, DDL trigger, etc., but this doesn't work for existing sessions.

Comment: Great, I got it ! Thank you a lot for the query which returns all the xe sessions and for making these things clear for me. In the end, I managed to accomplish what I intended to do.